# How to enable automatic Gzip compression wtih Google Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nestjs, google-cloud-run

I run a few Google Cloud Run services for internal tools and noticed the responses are not gzipped. Our frontend clients are Svelte apps.

Each request's headers contain the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header.

Wondering if there is a turnkey solution to enable gzip compression of responses – or whether I need to implement that in my NestJS backend?

Comment: AFAIK Cloud Run does provide response body compression. App Engine does in certain cases. It has been a while since I verified that, but Cloud Run has been advancing rapidly ...

Comment: What's the content type of the data that you serve?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere JSON, quite big arrays at times so Gzip would really help...